# circuit analysis with dependent voltage source

Tags: circuit-analysis

The question is:
[image]

### **The solution is as follows:**

[image]
[image]

### Everything is clear. I am only confused how he solved for "Loop 2:" in his solution. Below is my attempt kindly advise me of my mistake.

[image]

We know that  does not equal $$I_2\ne\frac{1}{2}*I_4$$, Because $$\frac{1}{2}*I_4$$ is a VOLTAGE and not a CURRENT. so, how are they equal?
This is my confusion.

The question and answer are from: FE Exam Review: Electrical and Computer Engineering 1st Edition by Myron E. Sveum Publisher : Professional Publications, Inc. ISBN-10 : 1591260698 ISBN-13 : 978-1591260691

Comment: I have read your question twice now and still don't understand it.. You need to make your question clearer. It might even be that you discover your mistake while doing so.. What is it that you are trying to solve? "loop 2: I_2 is that of the dependent source, 0.5 I_4" This is a statement (an obvious observation), not a solution to anything, what are you trying to solve?. Also, I really despise the whole "loop current" method, its awkward and unintuitive an there exist much better, easier and more straight-forward methods of solving this!.

Comment: @Vinzent I am sorry. my question is it accurate that $$i_2 = 0.5*i_4$$

Comment: No it is not, \$ 0.5 \cdot i_4 \$ is the potential of the controlled voltage source, in volts.